# Make a box and store the input in a variable tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, ping

I'm trying to make a ping tool with a GUI on tkinter. The thing is that i would like to create a box where you could enter a web domain and then click ping and ping to that web. right now I have to change the web to ping on the code (V1.0) but i really tried to make the changes mentioned above but they don`t seem to work.

This is the original code:

```
#Imports
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
import Tkinter as tk
from Tkinter import Tk
from threading import Thread


def create_worker(target):
    return Thread(target=target)

def start_worker(worker):
    worker.start()

#Ping printed on tkinter window root
def commande():
    cmd = 'ping -c 10 google.com'
    p = Popen(cmd.split(), stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
    for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, ''):
    result.configure(text=line)

#tkinter code
root = Tk()
root.title('PingTool')
root.geometry('450x70+400+400')

worker = create_worker(commande)
tk.Button(root, text='Ping', command=lambda:start_worker(worker)).pack()

result = tk.Label(root)
result.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

One not working version:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
import Tkinter as tk
from Tkinter import Tk
from threading import Thread

#intput on the console
u = input('Website to ping: ')

def create_worker(target):
    return Thread(target=target)

def start_worker(worker):
    worker.start()


def commande():
    cmd = 'ping -c 10 ' + u
    p = Popen(cmd.split(), stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)#
    for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, ''): #changes the text printed instead of printing multiple times
        result.configure(text=line)#

root = Tk()
root.title('PingTool')
root.geometry('450x70+400+400')

worker = create_worker(commande)
tk.Button(root, text='Ping', command=lambda: start_worker(worker)).pack()

result = tk.Label(root)
result.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

The 'not working version' has the 'problem' that the input is written on the console. The idea is to create a label and input the text there.
I know this might not be the best place to ask something like this because it seems that i just want the work done but trust me I've really tried.
Thank you

PD: I'm starting with tkinter.

Comment: Have a look at the [`Entry`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm) widget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

subprocess.check_output should be enough for what you want to do https://pymotw.com/2/subprocess/index.html#module-subprocess  A simple program follows that runs the command when the button is pressed, and prints the output.  I'll leave something for you to do, i.e. configure the text on a Label http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/label.htm and also you should add some code for an entry that is not a valid website.

```
import sys
if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
    import Tkinter as tk     ## Python 2.x
else:
    import tkinter as tk     ## Python 3.x

import subprocess

def button_callback():
    ent_contents=ent.get()
    output=subprocess.check_output("ping -c 10 "+ent_contents,
                                    shell=True)
    print "*****after", output, "\n"

root=tk.Tk()
ent=tk.Entry(root)
ent.grid(row=0, column=0)
ent.focus_set()

tk.Button(root, text="ping website", bg="lightblue",
          command=button_callback).grid(row=1, column=0)
tk.Button(root, text="Exit Program", bg="orange",
          command=root.quit).grid(row=2, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```